# SQL Server session in CLUSTER

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, session-state, nodes

Can anyone help me with this ...

I have a 3 node sql server cluster lets say N1, N2 and N3. The name for the three node cluster is SQLCLUS.
The application connects to database using the name SQLCLUS in connections strings name.

The application uses SQL Server session manangement. So I remote desktopped to N1 (which is active while N2 and N3 are passive)  and from the locaiton

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727

I executed the following command

aspnet_regsql.exe -S SQLCLUS -E -ssadd -sstype p

The command executed successfully. I could then login into SQLCLUS and see ASpState database created with 2 tables.

I then tested the applciation which uses the SQL Server session and it also works fine.

Now my question is ...

1. If there is a fail over to node N2 or N3 will my application still work ?. I did not execute the above command (aspnet_regsql.exe ) from N2.
2. Should I execute the command , aspnet_regsql.exe -S SQLCLUS -E -ssadd -sstype p , in N2 and N3 too ?
3. What changes happens in a sql server after executing the above command ?. I mean , is there any kind of service ot settings changes that can be seen ?.

Greatly apprecite any in puts regarding this....

Thanks in advance...

  3.

Comment: Assuming your connection string for the ASP.NET session state configuration points to the virtual server name, and not an individual node name, it will be fine on failover. You do not need to re-run the commands on individual nodes, since there is only one copy of the database, not (number of nodes).

Comment: You can run [aspnet_regsql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(v=vs.80).aspx) with the option -sqlexportlonly <filename> to nly get the script that will be executed. From that script you can learn what is changed. I doubt you have to run it on N2 or N3 as well..

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. I don't mean to doubt your knowledge here. Would it be possible to share some links which discusses similar situation. I have the production system running in above settings and want to make sure I do all the required settings before any fail over happens ?. Thanks again for the speedy response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql Server failover clustering can be conceptually explained as a smoke-and-mirrors dns hack.  Thinking of clustering in familiar terms makes you realize how simple a technology it really is.

### Simplified description of Sql Server Failover Clustering

Imagine you have two computers: SrvA and SrvB

You plug an external HD (F:) into SrvA,  Install Sql Server and configure it to store its database files on f:\  (The executable is under C:\Program Files).

Unplug the HD, plug it into SrvB, Install Sql Server and configure it to store its database files on F:\ in the exact same location.

Now, you create a dns alias "MyDbServer" that points to SrvA, plug the external HD back into SrvA, and start sql server.

All is good until one day when the power supply fails on SrvA and the machine goes down.

To recover from this disaster you do the following:

1. Plug the external drive into SrvB
2. Start sql server on SrvB
3. Tweak the dns entry for "MyDbServer" to point to SrvB.

You're now up and going on SrvB, and your client applications are blissfully unaware that SrvA failed because they only ever connected using the name "MyDbServer".

### Failover Clustering in the Reality

SrvA and SrvB are the **cluster nodes.**
The External HD is **Shared SAN Storage.**
The three step recovery process is what happens during a **cluster failover** and is managed automatically by the ***Windows Failover Clustering service.***

### What kinds of tasks need to be run on each Sql Node?

**99.99%** of the tasks that you perform in Sql Server will be stored in the database files on shared storage and therefore will move between nodes during a failover.  This includes everything from creating logins, creating databases, INSERTS/UPDATES/DELETES on tables, Sql Agent jobs and just about everything else you can think of. This also includes all of the tasks that aspnet_regsql command performs (it does nothing special from a database perspective).

The remaining **.01%** of things that would have to be done on each individual node (because they aren't stored on shared storage) are things like applying service packs (remember that the executable is on c:), certain registry settings (some Sql Server registry settings are **"checkpointed"** and failover, some aren't), registering 3rd party COM dll's (no one really does this anymore) and changing the service account that Sql Server runs under.

### Try it for yourself

If you want to verify that aspnet_regsql doesn't need to be run on each node, then try failing over and verify that your app still works.  If you do run aspnet_regsql on each node and reference the clustered name (SQLCLUS) then you will effectively be over-writing the database, so if it doesn't error out, it will just wipe out your existing data.